# I installed KVM via synaptic from Ubuntu repositories, and now my computer won't boot.

Tags: kvm, ubuntu-18.04

2 week old Ubuntu 18.04 install.

As a requirement of running a android device emulator for Android studio, I had to install KVM, so I installed it (the exact package name was kvm, it had some dependencies), and now my computer won't boot. It just sits there with a purple screen.

No keyboard or mouse input has any effect (including REISUB).

I have googled and nothing relevant comes up (it's all about booting VMs, understandably).

I have no idea what to do, especially since I cannot interact directly with my OS.

I still have my boot stick (that I used to install 18.04), and I can boot off that.

[image: I happened to take a picture to send to a friend to show why testing a pull request was taking so long]

[image: Android Studio requirement]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that installing linux-kvm actually doesn't install a VM program, it just installs another kernal that's obsolete, puts it at the top of the grub list, and that's how it breaks your computer.

I fixed it by using boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).